# How to create a specific Web App with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Can we make Web Apps in WordPress with specific (custom) scope, something like a mini-Facebook, a mini-Twitter, a stackoverflow, etc. What I really want to know is that how much am I free handed to build whatever Web App I want in WP? and more importantly how to?

Give me some references to books, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with WordPress and even more. You can even create mobile apps and web services. If you want a book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029380.do

If you want a starting tutorial, then go: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/build-a-web-app-with-wordpress/